# Prove if for every $n$ vertex simple graph $\alpha(G),\omega(G)\ge k$ then $n\ge2^{\frac{k}{2}}$

Tags: graph-theory

> If $k>1$ is an integer and for every simple $n$ vertex graph like $G$, $\alpha(G)\ge k$ and $\omega(G)\ge k$ then show $n\ge2^{\frac{k}2}$.

My attempt: I tried to prove the contrapostion, i.e for every $n\lt2^{\frac{k}2}$ there exists a $n$ vertex graph $G$ such that both $\alpha(G)\lt k$ and $\omega(G)\lt k$ holds.

Also if we construct an example only for the highest $n$ in the inequality, it's clear that we are done with the rest of the values, too.

But the examples I created moved the boundary to $k(k-1)$ which is too far from $2^{\frac{k}2}$, any suggestions?

Comment: Do $\alpha(G)$ and $\omega(G)$ represent the maximal sizes of an independent and a clique in $G$, respectively?

Comment: @Wore Yes, thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use a Theorem of Erdos that states that for every $k$, the Ramsey number of $k$ is at least $2^{k/2}$. To relate with your problem: if $R(k)\geq 2^{k/2}$ then, by definition of Ramsey number, for every $n<2^{k/2}$ there is a graph with $n$ vertices that does not contain neither a clique nor an anticlique of size $k$.

Comment: @Wore Thanks! I'm not familiar with this Theorem and the Ramsey number, I'd try to read about them and relate them to this problem as you said. But since it was an elementary exercise I thought maybe it didn't need advanced tools!

Comment: Here there is an explanation of the proof, using the probabilistic method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method

Comment: Theorem 2 here might also help http://www.its.caltech.edu/~nbalacha/Teaching/2009-10/The_Probabilistic_method_Combinatorics.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ramsey numbers lower bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244210/ramsey-numbers-lower-bound)