# Ramsey numbers lower bound

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I have been given the following information,

${\displaystyle {\binom {n}{k}}2^{1-{\binom {k}{2}}}} < 1 \ then \ R(k,k) > n$.

Now I wish to show that for $K \geq 3$

$ R(k,k) \geq \mathrm{2}^{0.5k} $

Not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively easy result using probabilistic method.

Take a $2$-coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$, where each edge is independently colored with color 1 with probability $1/2$.

For any $k$-clique $S$, the probability of $S$ being monochrimatic is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\binom{k}{2}-1}$ : $1/2$ for each edge and you have 2 colors available.

Then, if $X$ is the random variable representing the number of monochromatic $k$-clique in $K_n$, by linearity of expectations : 
$$ \mathbb{E}(X)=\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\binom{k}{2}-1}$$

You need to verify that for $n=2^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}$, $\mathbb{E}(X)<1$. Therefore, applying Markov inequality
$$ \mathbb{P}(X=0)>0$$
And there is a coloring of $K_n$ with $n=2^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}$, with no monochromatic $k$-clique. Hence $R(k,k) > 2^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}$

Comment: an relatively..

Comment: how does $P(X=0) > 0$ follow from Markov?

Comment: Markov states that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{a}$. Hence $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1)\geq 1-\mathbb{E}(X) >0 $.

Comment: But I just noticed that the OP asked not for this proof, but rather on to prove that $\mathbb{E}(X)<1$ for $n=2^{k/2}$... I'll update my answer

Comment: Just as a personal matter, I think all the probability language obscures what is really going on. You're just interchanging a summation and using pigeonhole. But to each his/her own I guess

Comment: @mathworker21, true, I'm used to deal with probability, but it can be non-necessarily confusing when you are not.